# Open generated PDF file into browser tab programmatically

Tags: jsf, primefaces, liferay, pdfbox

I have created Pdf file on click action of **Print**  button using `Apache PDFBox` api as shown below. As of now I saved that file into my drive(file system). What I need is to open up Pdf file directly into browser without saving into drive so that it can be print or download as require.

`TestPdfBean.java`

```
@ManagedBean(name = "pdfBean")
@ViewScoped
public class TestPdfBean implements Serializable {

    public void createAndOpenPdf() {
        PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
        PDPage page = new PDPage();
        document.addPage(page);

        PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;
        PDPageContentStream content = new PDPageContentStream(doc,page);

        content.beginText();
        content.setFont(font, 12);
        content.moveTextPositionByAmount(100, 700);
        content.drawString(" Generating Pdf content...");
        content.endText();

        content.close();
        document.save("/home/ck/Test/test.pdf");
        document.close();
    }
```

}

Code snippet of `test.xhtml`

```
<h:form id="pdfForm">
     <p:panelGrid columns="2">

        <h:outputText value="Create Pdf file.." />
        <p:commandButton value="Print" actionListener="#{pdfBean.createAndOpenPdf}" />

    </p:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

I have deployed above portlet into liferay-portal-6.1.1.

Is there any way to open up pdf file directly into browser by Primefaces Or by Jsf Or by Liferay ?

Comment: Were you able to implement this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you take a look at the Liferay Faces [jsf2-export-pdf-portlet](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-faces/tree/3.1.x/demos/bridge/jsf2-export-pdf-portlet) demo for Liferay 6.1. It has an example of a JSF 2.x ResourceHandler that enables the PDF to be generated and downloaded.

Comment: I found one link to handle pdf : [Pdf handling](http://balusc.blogspot.in/2006/05/pdf-handling.html) , Is it applicable ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, it will not work because the h:form would postback to a portlet ActionURL which does not have the ability to set the response content type. That is basically the same problem we encountered with PrimeFaces p:dataExporter which was fixed in [FACES-1513](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/FACES-1513). You could try adding f:ajax as a child of h:commandButton/h:commandLink but I'm not sure if that would work.

Answer (score 0):

Create an HttpServlet and give back the PDF in the response.
Then just link your commandButton to the URL of the servlet and you´re done ...

Comment: Since the HttpServlet does not participate in the portlet lifecycle, it would not be able to do any security checks against the current portal user. Instead I think it would be better to utilize the portlet RESOURCE_PHASE which is supported by the JSF 2 ResourceHandler concept thanks to the JSF Portlet Bridge.

Comment: @Neil your are right, HttpServlet is not applicable in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The browser will open the document if you return a ByteArrayOutputStream.

```
        `FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) context.getExternalContext().getResponse();
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachement;filename=Quote_.pdf");
        response.encodeRedirectURL("_blank");

        byte[] bytes = printPDFBean.createQuotationPDF(current, cfgDoc, cfgEntity, quoteDetailList, customer).toByteArray();
        response.getOutputStream().write(bytes);
        context.responseComplete();`
```

This code calls my createQuotationPDF method which returns ByteArrayOutputStream object. The issue is, the document is opened in the current window and not a new one.

```
       `public ByteArrayOutputStream createQuotationPDF(Quotation currentQuote, CfgDoc cfgDoc, CfgEntity cfgEntity, List<QuotationDetail> quoteDetailList, Customer customer) {

        String filePath = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("/");

        String imagesFolder = filePath + FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getInitParameter("smefin.images");
        String fontsFolder = filePath + FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getInitParameter("smefin.fonts");

        PDDocument doc = null;
        PDPage page = null;

        ByteArrayOutputStream output;
        output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try {

            doc = new PDDocument();
            page = new PDPage();
            doc.addPage(page);
            File fontLatoBlackFile = new File(fontsFolder + "Lato-Black.ttf");
            File fontLatoLiteFile = new File(fontsFolder + "Lato-Light.ttf");
            Encoding encoding = new WinAnsiEncoding();
            PDFont fontLatoBold = PDTrueTypeFont.load(doc, fontLatoBlackFile, encoding);
            PDFont fontLatoLite = PDTrueTypeFont.load(doc, fontLatoLiteFile, encoding);

                content.beginText();
                content.setFont(fontLatoBold, 11);
                content.newLineAtOffset(50, 60);
                content.showText("Text");
                content.endText();
            }

            doc.save("D:/TestData/Quote_.pdf");
            doc.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("" + e);
        }
        return output;
    }`
```